# Add anniversary to calendar

Tags: iphone, calendar

iOS calendar add birthdays but no anniversary.
How can I add them from the contacts to the calendar?

Comment: You can add an anniversary field in Contacts/Preferences/Templates with the pull down by choosing "Dates" but alas, it does not show up in the Calendar. No doubt that will come in some future version of Calendar. I thought I found the answer... at least we can put anniversary dates in Contacts and wait for the day Calendar inherits that field.

Answer (score 1):

Another work around would be to add a contact, called for exemple Wedding Me and My Wife and add a birthday to it. So it will show like a birthday in the calendar but you'll not it's an anniversary.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly through the iPhone, but, **[BirthDayScanner](http://www.zencat.de/bsx/index.html)** does exactly that.

It scans the **Address Book** for all dates. Then presents them to you, to choose and edit, or play around, and then generates events directly in **iCal** which can be synced with the **iPhone**.

Comment: There is something like this for windows?

Answer (score 0):

Asked quite some time ago, and the feature was not yet implemented.

But there is a work-around, using your friend Google.

In short:

- Create/use a Google mail account
- On https://contacts.google.com create a contact with birthday and/or other dates:

  [image]
- Add your Google account to your iOS/macOS device - how? read https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/99358
- In iOS Calendar, activate from that account the calendar **Birthday**
- See your contact's birthday and/or other dates in the Calendar app:

  [image]

(Please excuse the unprofessional screenshot)

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I can tell you how to add the field easily, but it doesn't seem to be widely supported.  (Only Fantastical 2 on my Mac seems to automatically import this into it's calendar.  I don't see it in the stock Calendar app on iOS or OSX, nor do I see it in Fantastical 2 on my iPhone.)

When editing a contact, click on + to add a new field.  Choose 'Date' from the options.  A new field will be added, and by default it will be of type 'Anniversary'.  Just fill in the original date of marriage here, and you're done.

Note:  I am using Google to sync contacts, but the field seems to be sync'ing correctly to my iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 12, go to Calendar > + > and at the bottom of the "New Event" screen, choose "Repeat" and select "Every Year." Alternatively, at the bottom of the "Repeat" screen, choose "Custom."

Answer (score -3):

free tool to remeber anniversaries..

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/anniversary-reminder/id614159715?mt=8

Comment: Can you please add some details about the app and why you are recommending it?